# Angular JSONP returning JSON_CALLBACK is not defined error

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to pull data down via JSONP with angular.  I've been puzzled as to why it won't work in certain situations.

I've been able to successfully pull in this sample JSONP:

https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Brian

But when copied to a bucket on S3, I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined`

The file is public and I can access it just fine with `$.ajax`, but not `$http.jsonp`

I've tried changing the MIME type for the json file to all of the following:

- application/json
- application/javascript
- application/x-javascript
- text/plain
- text/javascript

None of them have allowed me to make a successfull call through the `$http.jsonp` function

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined" — Your question is missing the code which defaults the JSON_CALLBACK function.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so this is very strange, but I eventually got it to work by changing the callback wrapper in the JSONP from `JSON_CALLBACK(.......)` to `angular.callbacks._0` because that's the callback function angular kept trying to call instead of JSON_CALLBACK... very weird behavior.

Comment: What is the version of angular.js you are using?

Comment: The `$http.jsonp` will replace the `JSON_CALLBACK` in url with the `angular.callbacks.{{callbackId}}` automatically. For some reason, it failed to do so in your case.

Comment: Yes, very weird behavior, but you saved my day anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to see your code, I can show you what worked for me a few days ago when working with JSONP and angular:

```
controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
var url = "https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Brian"
$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    });
}])
```

Then in the view, something like this should work:

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
{{greeting.name}} <br />
{{greeting.salutation}}
</div>
```

If this doesn't answer your question, try pasting in your code.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Brian I found out a method to make sure it detects `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`. When you request for the url, instead of putting the whole thing inside, you can write it this way, and it detects 100%:

```
$http({
  method: 'JSONP',
  url: 'https://angularjs.org/greet.php' + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' + '&name=Brian"'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Rest Answer or http `json` file on the bucket, need to be dynamic with the get(callback) parameter.

You need to detect the callback parameter and concat to the `json` to get the `jsonp`.

For Example:

```
1) http://example.com?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK
2) http://example.com?callback=OtherCallback
3) http://example.com?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK_OTHER
```

get the GET parameter "callback" and make your rest like this:

```
1) JSONP_CALLBACK({YOUR REST INFO})
2) OtherCallback({YOUR REST INFO})
3) JSONP_CALLBACK_OTHER({YOUR REST INFO})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `JSONP_CALLBACK` instead of `JSON_CALLBACK`

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Change your response from server by

```
angular.callbacks._0 ({"name":"Super Hero","salutation":"Namaste","greeting":"Namaste Super Hero!"});
```

instead of

```
JSON_CALLBACK ({"name":"Super Hero","salutation":"Pryvitannie","greeting":"Pryvitannie Super Hero!"});
```